# Кому надо это [node]?

Tags: предложение, статус-завершено, удаление-метки

Заметил, что на некоторые вопросы по Node.js добавляется метка [node](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/node), которая никак не связана синонимом с основными метками: [node.js](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/node.js) и синонимом [nodejs](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nodejs).
Прошу заметить, что на StackOverflow EN метка [node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/node) и вовсе отсутвствует, получается что сама по себе эта метка не несет никакого смыслового значения, чтобы использовать ее на других видах вопросов, не связанных с Node.js. Делать ее синонимом к [node.js](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/node.js) мне кажется тоже нет смысла.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Метка [node](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/node) уничтожена: где-то удалена, где-то заменена на [node.js](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/node.js).

Так как вопросов с бывшей меткой мало, а замена более-менее прямолинейна (надо только акуратно проверять использование в каждом случае), то можно исправить без лишних обсуждений.