# Вероятная ошибка в наполнении блока «Обсуждаемое на Мете»

Tags: дефект, статус-не-воспроизводится, мета, блок-важных-вопросов

В данный момент на Мете есть несколько вопросов, которые достаточно интенсивно обсуждаются и получают много просмотров, например

- [Проблемы причины закрытия "опросник" и возможные решения](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1918/181472) (за два дня 148
  просмотров, 5 ответов, 33 голоса в сумме, 31 комментарий)
- [Вы сломали мой StackOverflow, часть 1: "опросники" должны умереть!](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1924/181472) (за два дня 85
  просмотров, 1 ответ, 12 голосов в сумме, 10 комментариев)

При этом как на Мете, так и на основном сайте справа в блоке популярных вопросов вижу только этот вопрос:

- [Кому надо это [node]?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1934/181472) (за один день 14 просмотров, 1 ответ, 6 голосов в сумме, 0 комментариев)

Похоже, информационный блок показывает совсем не то, что реально обсуждается на Мете.

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: С тех пор больше не было таких случаев, так что нет возможности локализовать и изучить возможный баг. Поэтому отмечаю как невоспроизводимое.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В стареньком посте "[How are the contents of the Community Bulletin determined?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/130893)" на Meta Stack Overflow перечислены критерии для попадания постов в блок "Community Bulletin". С тех пор функционал блока заметно изменился, и информацию можно считать потерявшей актуальность, как минимум, частично, но, вероятно, что-то продолжает работать по-старому. Здесь интересен один пункт:

> - If there are still under 4 items, the rest of the space is filled with **[hot](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11602/what-formula-should-be-used-to-determine-hot-questions) [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) questions** not marked [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed), scoring at least 3 and posted within the past two weeks. These are picked semi-randomly. At least *one* of these will always be added to the list, even if it pushes the length over 4. (Note that the timing and tags [can be adjusted per-site](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268576/why-do-feature-requests-and-support-questions-appear-in-the-community-bulletin/268577#268577) to suit the needs of each community)

Из этого можно вынести следующую информацию:

1. Популярные вопросы вытесняются остальными, но всегда отображается, как минимум, один.
2. Популярность определяется как вписывание в некоторые числовые рамки по оценке, дате и т. п. Эти рамки настраиваются на уровне сайта.
3. Вопросы выбираются случайным образом среди всех "популярных".
4. По умолчанию в блоке отображаются только вопросы с меткой [обсуждение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%81%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5) ([discussion](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/discussion)).
5. На уровне сайта есть настройка, вопросы с какими метками отображать.
6. Скрываются вопросы с закрытым обсуждением.

Что это нам даёт? Во-первых, это объясняет, почему в блок "Интересное на Мете" ни разу не попали мои посты "Вы сломали мой Stack Overflow": все они отмечены как [дефект](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%84%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82) ([bug](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bug)). Правда несколько настораживает, что также не попадал в этот блок пост @PashaPash, потому что уж он-то точно является популярным, при этом отмечен как [обсуждение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%81%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5) ([discussion](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/discussion)).

На правах теории заговора: если это действительно так, а мне и вам не показалось, и в систему не прокрался баг, который работат только на нашем сайте†, то можно сделать предположение, что метка [причины-закрытия](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%8b-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%80%d1%8b%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%8f) внесена в настройках как исключающая попадание в блок "Интересное на Мете", или проделан какой-то аналогичный финт ушами. :-)

<sub>† На большом СО в блоке "Hot Meta Posts" всплывало множество действительно горячих обсуждений, особенно вскоре после разделения на MSE и MSO. Чего стоит один легендарный пост про негативность.</sub>

Comment: убрал метку, сейчас проверим, как работает.

Comment: @NickVolynkin Рапортую: пост PashaPash на СО, мой пост №1 на Мете (в аналогичном блоке). В своих постах я поменял "дефект" на "обсуждение", но оставил "причины-закрытия" и "нытьё". Теория с "обсуждением" подтвердилась, теорию с "причинами-закрытия" надо анализировать дальше. Правда эксперимент нельзя считать чистым.

Comment: ага, вижу что теперь все вопросы видны. Но при этом еще и три [featured] исчезли. Возможно, такое поведение проявляется только когда остается лишь одном место. То есть выбирается не самый популярный вопрос, а один из отвечающих критериям — а таковых довольно много.

Comment: @NickVolynkin Выбирается-то один, но в ротации должно быть много. Суть в том, что в ротации не было ни одного вопроса про опросники. Я не встречал, скажем. Теперь интересный вопрос — появятся ли мои в блоке на главном сайте. / Кстати, теперь ещё стало ясно, что срок, как минимум, порядка двух недель.